# Mono GetText on .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, mono, gettext, monodevelop

I have a problem with my app, using gtk# and Mono/.NET 3.5
MonoDevelop (which im using) under Linux shows all strings to translation, but monodevelop on windows - shows nothing.
is there a way to make it work or is any another cross-platform solution to add multi-language to it?

thanks in advance

Comment: Which versions of mono/gtk#/monodevelop are you using?

Comment: none/2.12.9/2.2, i don't use Mono on windows - only .NET 3.5, on Linux i have 2.4.3 but its all ok on this OS

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about the Translation addin for MonoDevelop, it does not work on Windows:

http://monodevelop.com/Download/What%27s_new_in_MonoDevelop_2.2#Feature_Matrix

Comment: Seems like they've added support for this in version 2.8 :)

Answer (score 2):

Try [Gettext.NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gettextnet/) port. This is a pure Mono/.NET implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can see why MonoDevelop in Windows doesn't have it (maybe some needed dependency, probably a native one), and see if you could contribute code/build muscle to make it available.

AFAIR, most of of the magic behind it is managed code in the specific addin.

See http://monodevelop.com/Developers, on how to contribute to make Monodevelop a better tool for you and for everybody.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [Vernacular](https://github.com/rdio/vernacular).